# How to prevent proguard from removing "module-info.class" from the output jar?

Tags: java, gradle, proguard, java-platform-module-system

I'm upgrading a Java desktop application to JDK10 and need to leverage modules to use the `javapackager` to build a native package.

Everything was working great until I added an obfuscation step using Proguard (6.0.2).
Once I enabled obfuscation (using a working proguard configuration file from the < JDK9 project) it works as expected but Proguard removes the `module-info.class` from the output JAR which prevents `javapackager` from finding the module.

According to Proguard's documentation for the `injars` parameter

> By default, any non-class files will be copied without changes.

The problem here is that `module-info.class` is a "class" file (albeit a weird one). The "keep" rules depend on class names so I don't think there is any rule I can use to prevent this removal.

How can I get Proguard to keep the `module-info.class` file?

Comment: This looks like a useful product. I plan to give it a try as well, assuming that this hitch that you discovered is resolved! I'm curious about what you have tried. Looking at the "Keep Overview" https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#keepoverview it seems like a simple -keep should both keep the module-info.class from being either renamed or removed. Can you go into more detail, actually show how you use the -keep option with module-info.class? Good luck on this!

Comment: That's the thing, although the `module-info.class` ends in `.class` it's not a class file. And according to the manual the `-keep` options need to be followed by the class specification https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#classspecification. The problem is that the file doesn't hold a class/interface/enum, just the description of the module. From what I've read, the version I used (6.0.2) should already support JDK9, so it would be natural for it to ignore the file but it's not.

Comment: Is the software maker providing responsive support? Also, am wondering if there is some sort of annotation that can be added to module-info to protect it from deletion. I will watch for updates here, and will update myself once I reach this step if I figure anything helpful out.

Comment: Yes, the author was very helpful, check my answer below

Comment: Thanks for follow-up. As for myself, I decided to go with Inno-Setup 5 and forego obfuscation, and am finding that route for packaging is working. (Am packaging resulting file system of JLINK operation on project.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [filing a bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/704/), Proguard's author confirmed that we need to treat `module-info` as just another class and add a rule to keep it, like this:

`-keep class module-info`

and possibly using

`-keepattributes Module*`

In my case, I actually had tried it before posting the question but it didn't work for me on the project I was using it with (I got a `NullPointerException` when I tried it, more details in the bug report)

After the author's response, I tried it on a simpler project and the "keep" rule above worked fine so it meant that something specific to my first project was causing the issue.

I worked around the issue in that project for now by using gradle to copy the `module-info.class` from the unobfuscated jar into the obfuscated one. It's not pretty but it works.

Hope this helps anyone in the same situation.

Comment: I still get an error saying there is a class file incorrectly named now

Comment: For reason I dont understand this did not work for me when I added the keepattributes  like this keepattributes 'Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,Module*' but it worked when I added another keepattributes Module* line. 
I should also note it was written directly in gradle and not in configuration file. Sorry for downvoting the answer, unfortunately I cannot change it anymore.

Comment: It did not work for us with the given defintion. We're using "-dontwarn module-info" as option now.

Comment: Those 2 options work for me in keeping the module-info classes, however it's not working. It's as if ProGuard is copying the main jar's module-info to the others, since I'm getting this error from jlink: Two versions of module X found. I have multiple jars, each having their own module. Running `jar --describe-module --file a.jar` shows each non-main jar in ProGuard output matches the main one, but input jars are fine.

Comment: Seems like would be a common problem for anyone using modules. With ProGuard 7 released for Java 14 support, still an issue for us to deal with it some hacky way. I guess I'm going to have to choose "Print mapping" under Obfuscation, and write a script for my build process to parse that mapping and copy over the module-info classes with updated (obfuscated) references to exported packages etc.